# Youtube API - Program type already present: com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Builder

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I follow this tutorial to create Youtube application: 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858

But when I built it, I have a error:

> Program type already present:
>   com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Activities$Insert
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Activities$Insert,
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

And logcat runs non-stop.

Comment: Please add your gradle file's code.

Answer (score 0):

the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev192-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > 
"Migrate to AndroidX" from the menu bar.

Select Build > Clean project

Restore Android Studio
Now, I'm using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and AndroidX in my project (Match4App) and I was able to publish it without any issues.

Comment: This task also allowed me to upgrade all other libraries that depend on AndroidX (i.e. com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2, com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:18.0.1, com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0, com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0, etc.).